# Работа вариативных шаблонов с++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

При написании вариативных шаблонов функций:

```
template <typename... T>
void foo(T... args) 
{
    foo(args...);
}
```

Можно увидеть вот такую запись:
`args...`

Насколько я понимаю,это развертка текущего пакета параметров, и передача его в `foo`. Но есть вопрос, что из себя представляет пакет параметров? Это какой-то особый тип данных или что? Как функция "видит" эту запись?

Comment: Просто вместо `... ` подставляются переданные параметры, вот и все. Т. Е. Это не райтанм передача, а на этапе анализа кода.